# Read bytes file from AWS S3 into AWS SageMaker conda_python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Good morning,
Yesterday I saved a file from SageMaker conda_python3 to S3 like this:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id='XXXX',
            aws_secret_access_key='XXXX'
        )
y = pandas.DataFrame(df.tag_factor,index = df.index)
s3.put_object(Body = y.values.tobytes(), Bucket='xxx', Key='xxx')
```

Today I am trying to open it with conda_python3 as a pandas.Series or as a numpy.array object, with this code:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id='XXX',
            aws_secret_access_key='XXX'
        )
y_bytes = s3.get_object(Bucket='xxx', Key='xxx')
y = numpy.load(io.BytesIO(y_bytes['Body'].read()))
```

but I am getting this error: OSError: Failed to interpret file <_io.BytesIO >object at 0x7fcb0b403258> as a pickle

I tried this:

```
y = numpy.fromfile(io.BytesIO(y_bytes['Body'].read()))
```

and I get this error:

> UnsupportedOperation: fileno

I tried this:

```
y = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(y_bytes['Body'].read()), sep=" ", header=None)
```

and I get this error:

> EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

How can I read this file?

Comment: First, please don't (ever) use secret keys in your notebook. This is not secure and will lead to data loss and hackers breaking into your environment. Your notebook has an IAM role that should allow it to access your S3 buckets. Second, use files as an intermediate location for your reading and writing from and to S3. It will be simpler both for your python code and to do 's3 cp' or other simple S3 commands on files/objects.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a previous comment, you probably want to save your data into a known file format for reading from and writing data to S3.

As an example, here is some code that converts a pandas DataFrame to csv, saves it in S3, and reads the file from S3 back into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd 
import boto3 
import io 

df = pd.dataFrame(...) 
csv_buffer = io.StringIO() 
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False) 
s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
bucket = 'mybucket' 
key = 'myfile.csv' 
s3.put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key) 

obj = s3.get_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key) 
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(object['Body'].read()))
```